# What is the proper grammar for ++i and i++ in compiler design?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, compiler-optimization, yacc

I have a value quad(quadruple) in my quad.c and my grammar for Increment operator is :

```
IrDr  : INCR Id     { $$ = qOp('+', $2, qUo('V',1));}  /* ++i */
  | Id INCR         { $$ = qOp('+', qUo('V',1), $1);}  /* i++ */
  ;
```

Problem is that when I evaluate this statement

```
i = 12;
k=++i;
print(i);                           
print(k);
```

It prints 12,13 instead it should print 13,13.

```
qUo('V',1)                  //returns tha target value 1
qOp('+', $2, qUo('V',1));}  //addition of the values.
```

Should I need to add something in grammar or I need to change my syntax directed translation.

Comment: I think it's impossible for us to tell from the code fragment shown how your translation is accommodating or interpreting the pre-increment and post-increment operators.  Further, you probably can't easily show us enough of the code; it is likely to be too complex to be a good fit on SO.  It is not clear how your `q0p` function is told the difference between pre-increment and post-increment. Note that in C, you can have expressions such as `++*ptr` and `(*ptr)++` (where the latter is different from `*ptr++`).  It is not clear that your code can handle those, or variations on the theme.

Comment: it won't handle pointers it is just for variables moreover, in simple words qOp function has case statement for operators that generates target code for two operands and adds then in case '+'. and returns that target variable.

Comment: Then the problem is in your `qOp()` function; it is not set up to distinguish between `+` and pre-increment and post-increment.  Not surprisingly, therefore, it does it wrong.  Neither `++i` nor `i++` is the same as `i + 1` (and `++i` is essentially the same as `i += 1` but `i++` is definitely not).

Comment: But it is increasing the value of k not i so I need to sort out that when I do i++ or ++i it should increase value of i. Thanks i'll try

Comment: That is consistent with your code thinking `++i` was the same as `i+1`. k would be 13, and i would be 12.

Comment: What should I do in syntax directed translation for increasing value of i ?

Comment: Handle it as though it were `i = i + 1`. Note that the difference between `++i` and `i++` is not the same as the difference between `1+i`  and `i+1`. (The second pair have identucal values, but the first pair are actually different from each other.)